# NoMethodError in Customer#checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me resolve this NoMethodError I keep getting?

```
undefined method `full_name' for #<Customer:0x007fb3d2c672c0>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<%= form_for(@customer, as: 'customer', url: {action: "create"}) do |f| %>

     <%= f.label :full_name, 'Name', :class => 'checkout-label' %>

     <%= f.text_field :full_name, :placeholder => 'Name', :class => 'checkout-input', :required => true %>

<% end %>
```

Here's what's listed in my customer_controller.rb:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController

 def checkout
  @customer = Customer.new
 end

 def create
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  render :confirm
 end

 def confirm
 end 

private

 def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:full_name, :email, :account_number, :disclaimer)
 end

end
```

And this is in my customer.rb:

```
validates_presence_of :full_name,
                    :email,
                    :account_number,
                    :disclaimer
```

Where am I not defining the method?

Comment: What's the model for Customer?

Comment: What is in your `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: I generated the migration to create the attribute, but now I'm getting this error when I run `rake db:migrate`: `permission denied for relation schema_migrations`

Comment: @Francine just show your migration, inside the post...

Answer (score 0):

You likely forget to run the migration to create the `first_name` attribute. Try this:

```
rails g migration add_first_name_to_customers first_name:string
```

Then migrate your database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Indeed, I did! But now I'm getting this error when I run `rake db:migrate`: 
`permission denied for relation schema_migrations`

Comment: What database are you using? If you are using postgres, you might be seeing this error because you didn't add your psql role. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013292/pgerror-error-permission-denied-for-relation-schema-migrations